# Problem sending ftp file using SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ftp

I am trying to send a file by ftp using a stored procedure in SQL Server.

When I run the procedure I get;

```
'OPTS':command not implemented.
```

after the first line of the script and then;

```
PORT address does not match originator.
```

after the 'put' command.

The stored procedure is;

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestFTP]
@FTPScriptFile nvarchar(128)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FTPCommand nvarchar(256)
    Set @FTPCommand = 'ftp -s:' + @FTPScriptFile
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @FTPCommand
END
RETURN
```

The ftp script file contains;

```
open ftp.jht.co.uk 21
username
password
binary
put "D:\TestFiles\SampleFile.csv"
disconnect
bye
```

Any idea as to the problem?

Thanks for taking the time to look and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Honestly, just don't do this using `xp_cmdshell`; doing stuff like this is a clutch at best. Use something better designed for this, like Powershell.

Comment: Sounds like you need to set it Passive mode either on or off `-p` or `-A`. This question has nothing to do with SQL Server and everything to do with `ftp` see https://linux.die.net/man/1/ftp

Comment: SQL Server SSIS has a built-in FTP Task.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to take a look at the first suggestion which was to use Powershell instead and that worked.

I created a stored procedure to create a script file;

```
$Directory = "D:\TestFiles"
$filename = "Example.csv"
$fullfile = "D:\TestFiles\Example.csv"
$ftpserver = "ftp://ftp.jht.co.uk/"
$username = "user"
$password = "pwd"
$ftpserverURI = New-Object -TypeName System.Uri -ArgumentList $ftpserver, [System.UriKind]::Absolute
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.NetworkCredential -ArgumentList $username, $password
$uri = New-Object -TypeName System.Uri -ArgumentList $ftpserverURI, $filename
$webclient.UploadFile($uri, [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::UploadFile, $fullfile)
```

And then ran the script with powershell;

```
DECLARE @Command nvarchar(256)
Set @Command = 'powershell "' + @ScriptFile + '"' 
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @Command
```

Thanks to everyone who took a look and suggested a solution.